# How to get "\u20ac" from € in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

Using utf8 encoding, I know

```
a = "\u20ac"

#=> "€"
```

I'm wondering is there anyway that reverse this process to get the "\u20ac" from string €?

like

```
a.get_encoding_method 

#=> "\u20ac"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
escaped = '\u' + a.unpack('U')[0].to_s(16)
```

Comment: wow, works like a charm! so unpack('U') return the decimal utf8 representation of a, then convert it to hex, isn't it?

Comment: Yes — `a.unpack('U')[0]` gives the Unicode codepoint as an integer, and we just need to convert that to a base-16 string.

Comment: thanks, codepoint, that's the term I want to use next time, BTW String#codepoint may serve the same way, but also require to convert into hex

Answer (score 0):

Try `'\u%x' % a.ord`. (assuming you want to end up with a string with a literal backslash and `u`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pack and unpack to convert back and forth. For example:

```
'€'.unpack('U*')
=> [8364]

[8364].pack('U*')
=> "€"
```